# Analog Circuit Modelling in Simscape (Simulink) doesn't work (No Input sighted)

Tags: analog, simulation, matlab, simulink, multiplier

I tried rebuilding the analog circuit for the Lorenz Attractor in Simulink using Simscape toolbox. Luckily they have also an analog multiplier circuit built-in and I re-wired everything just as the book advices: The Art of Electronics: The x Chapters

[image]

I am not sure, where my mistake is. I don't have a signal source whatsoever, I don't get how this circuit is suppose to work in the first place, so no wonder I'm getting only zero

[image]

Where is the input? How is this circuit valid?
If someone also have Simulink, they can try to open my model and look for themself.

Comment: did you specify the "beginning value" for the "capacitor voltage" in the variables for all the capacitor's block parameters? please try with 5V.